# Eclipse - How to run 2 junit tests

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I would like to run 2 tests methods using eclipse.
I can run 1 test, and whole test class, but 2 test method is impossible.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 6):

write a test suite which includes your tests, like

```
public static Test suite(){
  TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
  suite.addTest(new BookTest("testEquals"));
  suite.addTest(new BookTest("testBookAdd"));
  return suite;
}
```

and run this suite instead of the single tests. See [this tutorial](http://www.laliluna.de/articles/eclipse-junit-testing-tutorial.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use JUnit4 syntax then try

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        JunitTest1.class,
        JunitTest2.class
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also select your test source directory or a package and right-click it and select "Run As -> Junit Test" to execute all tests in that source directory or package.

Answer (score 0):

Mark as comment the test methods you don't like to run.
Run the class as J-Unit test.